# How to get the same nodes like in Chrome Performance Monitor

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-inspector

Chrome 64 brings a new feature: [Performance Monitor](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/devtools-release-notes#perf-monitor)

In my app the number is increasing all the time so I need to fix it.

I can't find out which nodes are increasing. I wrote a small javascript function to collect all dom Nodes and it does not get the same number at the end.

Why the number found by the function is not the same like the one deliver by the performance monitor?

```
function allNodes(node, result) {
    var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(node.childNodes);
    result = result.concat(nodes);
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      var child = nodes[i];
      result = allNodes(child, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

[image]

Here is the HTML I tried with:

```
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>
Hello world
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the expected result of the function?

Comment: I expect all nodes of the document.

Comment: How do you know that at the time the function is executed the total nodes of the `document` is not `399`?

Comment: Because 650 is always stable and never change

Comment: What do you mean by "In my App the number is increasing all the time so I need to fix it."? Can you include the HTML that you are trying the JavaScript with at the Question?

Comment: I made the test with google.com, now I put a very simple webpage.

Comment: Is the result for the example HTML document at the Question `7` using the `allNodes` function?

Comment: yes this is correct, I wonder why the Performance Monitor is telling 171...

Comment: Not sure. A bug? We could try to count each character of each text node, and new line characters to determine if that is how the node are counted. You can ask the authors and contributors how the `DOM Nodes` metric is calculated at the mailing list and issue links

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a view of your DOM tree, it's a view of the browser's render process. I don't know exactly what it all means, but it counts things that are not actually "Nodes", and it also depends on the behavior of the garbage collector.

With your snippet of HTML I can consistently get 8 nodes in the performance monitor, but *only* in a fresh renderer. I can also find exactly 8 nodes with the following query:

```
> queryObjects(EventTarget)
Array(8)
0: Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …}
1: Window {frames: Window, …}
2: Window {TEMPORARY: 0, PERSISTENT: 1, constructor: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Window"}
3: WindowProperties {constructor: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "WindowProperties"}
4: Node {ELEMENT_NODE: 1, ATTRIBUTE_NODE: 2, TEXT_NODE: 3, CDATA_SECTION_NODE: 4, ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE: 5, …}
5: Document {…}
6: document
7: HTMLDocument {constructor: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "HTMLDocument"}
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I chose `EventTarget` because it seems to be the common base prototype of all kinds of `Node`. So this is my best guess as to what this number represents: A more generic type of Node than you might expect, plus a lot of garbage.

So if you actually want to count the number of nodes in your document, I would go ahead and use this [queryObjects](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#query-objects) call.

The number 8 in the performance monitor immediately jumps up by tens, hundreds of nodes as soon as I move the mouse over the output above, or open the elements tab, or do pretty much anything. The debugger itself causes the renderer to slow down and produce more garbage, and there probably isn't any way around that.

And to specifically address your question, is it possible to find these nodes? Given the hypothesis that these objects are waiting to be garbage collected, or are otherwise referenced in the internals of the renderer but are not reachable from the document, the answer has to be no, if there is no API for accessing information about the garbage collector.

And this is speculation, but remember that V8 has *isolated worlds*, which share the underlying C++ DOM objects but have their own DOM wrapper objects. This performance monitor is probably counting the underlying C++ DOM objects, which are not directly reachable.

[image]

Comment: Confusing naming convention for the feature?

Comment: Thanks for the `queryObjects(EventTarget)` trick, I think it will help to resolve my original problem. I think DOM Nodes also count elements which are not attached to the DOM anymore. `childNodes` ignores them.